# SQL Update Table Based on Join and Multiple Where Clauses

Tags: mysql

I am trying to retrieve appointments from clients whose status is 1 and update it to 0. This is my select statement :

```
select  *
    from  tbl_appointment
    left join  tbl_client  ON tbl_client.id = tbl_appointment.client_id
    WHERE  tbl_client.mfl_code = '10808'
      AND  tbl_appointment.app_status = 'LTFU'
      AND  tbl_appointment.active_app = 1;
```

I get the correct results. I am trying to update the appointment table, specifically the active_app column based on this select statement, but i cant seem to get the query right.
My two attempts look like this:

This yields a syntax error `left join tbl_client on (tbl_client.id = tbl_appointment.c' at line 2`

```
UPDATE tbl_appointment
    SET active_app = 0
from tbl_appointment
left join tbl_client on tbl_client.id = tbl_appointment.client_id
WHERE (tbl_client.mfl_code = '10808'
  AND  tbl_appointment.app_status = 'LTFU'
  AND  tbl_appointment.active_app = 1)
```

And this updates everything

```
update tbl_appointment 
left join tbl_client
    on (tbl_client.id = tbl_appointment.client_id
    AND tbl_client.mfl_code = '10808'
    AND tbl_appointment.app_status = 'LTFU'
    AND tbl_appointment.active_app = 1)
set tbl_appointment.active_app = 0 ;
```

And this :

```
UPDATE  A
SET A.active_app = 0 
FROM tbl_appointment AS A left join tbl_client AS B on B.id = A.client_id
WHERE (B.mfl_code = '10808' AND A.app_status = 'LTFU' AND A.active_app = 1)
```

Any pointers to how to update based on joint tables will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- You don't want `LEFT`.
- Forget about the version with the syntax error.
- If you are going to do both the `SELECT` and the `UPDATE`, add `FOR UPDATE` to the `SELECT` and put them between `START TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT`.
- If the tables are large, these indexes should help:

  ```
    tbl_client:  INDEX(mfl_code, id)
    tbl_appointment:  INDEX(app_status, active_app, client_id)
  ```

Comment: `START TRANSACTION;
SELECT mfl_code, clinic_number FROM tbl_client WHERE mfl_code = '10808' FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE tbl_appointment SET active_app = '0'
WHERE active_app = '1' and app_status = 'LTFU';
COMMIT 
`    All my records are still being updated, should i add a where clause in the update as well?

Comment: @shiro - The Update must precisely specify which rows to update.  What you have is not what I was referring to.  The transaction and `FOR UPDATE` are usually used when you need to fetch some stuff, process it outside SQL, then proceed with an Update or Delete.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked

```
UPDATE tbl_appointment
JOIN tbl_client ON tbl_client.id = tbl_appointment.client_id 
SET active_app = '0' 
WHERE
    tbl_client.mfl_code = '10808' 
    AND tbl_appointment.app_status = 'Defaulted'
    AND tbl_appointment.active_app = '1';
```